# NextJS cookie-parser middleware absent from production build

Tags: node.js, build, middleware, next.js

I'm developing a NextJS application and have been using `npm run dev` during the development process. Now I'm trying to do a production build as described on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#production-deployment).

My app blows up in production mode; it seems the `cookie-parser` node middleware is not installed in the production build? Here is how I set it up:

**server.js**

```es6
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // require cookie-parser

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(cookieParser());                // use cookieParser

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
    });
})
.catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
})
```

Later in the code I access the node `req` object. In development mode [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies) is present as I would expect. In production mode it's absent.

It looks like there is no *server.js* file in the production build directory. What's more, grepping for `cookie-parser` and `cookieParser` in said production build directory yields empty results.

Any idea what's going on and how to get `cookie-parser` working in a production NextJS build?

Answer (score 1):

[Found the answer](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing) on the same GitHub page.

> When using a custom server with a server file, for example called
>   server.js, make sure you update the scripts key in package.json to:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
}
```

One problem with the production build down!